# CSS - border-radius

Tags: css

Всем доброго времени суток, возник вопросик с раздела CSS. В данной таблице имеется функция **border-radius**, в ее задания входит округления, а существует ли какая либо функция которая округляла либо верх либо низ? Если нету такой функции, как можно справить с данной задачей?

Comment: Комбинируйте: Комбинируйте: [border-bottom-left-radius](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-bottom-left-radius), [border-bottom-right-radius](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-bottom-right-radius), [border-top-left-radius](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-top-left-radius), [border-top-right-radius](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-top-right-radius)

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Вот вам [примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/zKsfT/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-radius)